# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) with libgimp3.0

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg, gimp, 18.10

I'm getting the above error when I try and update my system.

I have tried to `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as well as `sudo apt install -f gimp`, `sudo apt remove gimp` and `sudo apt purge gimp`. I even tried to do the recommended `sudo apt --fix-broken install` via Recovery to no avail.

Due to being super frustrated and after some searching, I even tried to `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/polar-bookshelf.* /tmp` but I'm still seeing no joy in getting this fixed. Can someone suggest a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

In terminal type `sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/gimp.postinst`

Then find `set -e` and replace it with `# set -e`, save and close.

Then type `sudo apt-get -f install`

Before `sudo apt update`

And finally `sudo apt upgrade`

The issue should be fixed.

Comment: Fine but what was the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error is:

1. gimp2.99 as a development version try to update gimp2.0 to gimp3.0 recently.
2. But there is a dependency of libgimp2.0 to sane and gimp-gmic (if you have installed them), so that in the coarse of update, gimp2.99 cannot remove libgimp2.0 and caused the problem.
3. If you want to test the development version of gimp for the gimp team, you may want to have libgimp3.0. To achieve this, first purge gimp and then remove libgimp2.0 together with gimp-gmic and sane (you can only do this if you do not need them) .Reinstall libgimp3.0 and gimp then.
4. I believe you won't have libgimp3.0 installed with former solution and you may have difficulty in updating gimp 2.99 in the future
5. If you need gmic very much while you like gtk3 of 2.99, do 4. and then download and run gimp appimage 2.10.8 with plugin. Then you can have both development version and stable version + plugin on your platform. this is what i do.

Comment: How would one purge gimp when the error has totally locked up dpkg. Meaning I can't install or remove any packages.

Apparently `sudo apt-get purge gimp* libgimp* -f` was enough

Comment: You have to remove the relevant packages "by force": sudo  dpkg --purge --force-all  YOUR PACKAGE(gimp, sane,gimp-gmic,libgimp2.0, gimp-data) You have to test the sequence of pakckages because there are inter-dependency if you have conflicts during uninstallation. Then reboot your machine. Then type in sudo dpkg --configure -a. Then reinstall gimp(sudo apt install gimp). If the installation block by lock, remove the lock( sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend). Reconfigure again(sudo dpkg --configure -a). Then sudo apt install gimp,